# How to save string greater than NVARCHAR(MAX) into a local T-SQL variable?

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, max, nvarchar

I have a very huge results that needs to be provided as an HTML.

This is the query:

```
DECLARE @N_Data NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SET @N_Data = 
            (SELECT 
                '<td>' + N_code + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + N_Title + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + N_Description + '</td>'
            FROM NTable             
            ORDER BY N_code                 
            FOR XML PATH('tr'))
SELECT @N_Data
```

I know this is not the best way of getting the data. Let's say that I am in certain circumstances that limit my options in just using this method.

So, when I check the results, it doesn't display everything because the result string is greater than `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

I know that using `TEXT` and `NTEXT` datatypes is not allowed with local variables.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You are outside the storage of NVARCHAR(max)? That is 2GB of storage. How long is your string? Please provide a sample record that would be found in NTable.

Comment: The query combining three fields as a string out of a table with more than 10000 records. Additionally, the last field which is the description is too long. Now imagine all this multiply 10000

Comment: Doesn't display everything *where*? In SSMS output? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, the display on SSMS and then I supposed to test it in an HTML file. When I limit the query (for example TOP 50) , it does display everything

Comment: As the link provided by Aaron Bertrand suggests, SSMS is probably showing you partial results, even if the entire select results are well within the range of `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: SSMS won't show you the whole thing, nor will it work that way if you copy and paste from SSMS into an HTML file. You need something that is capable of taking that large output and placing it directly into the HTML file, you won't be able to do this with SSMS.

Comment: As you describe it, I guess that you want to display the data as `HtmlTable` into a web page. For sure the is a performance problem as well as usability problem, fetching and displaying at once more than 10000 rows, at any form. Maybe paging is your solution.

Comment: Even if this works, displaying it in a browser is going to be very hard.

Answer (score 0):

**nvarchar(max) aside, the string concatination caught my eye.**

Perhaps another approach

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,N_Code varchar(25),N_Title varchar(50),N_Description varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'ABC','Title For ABC','Description for ABC and some additional text'),
(1,'123','Title For 123','Description for 123 and more text')

Declare @N_Data nvarchar(max) = (
Select  td=N_Code
       ,null
       ,td=N_Title
       ,null
       ,td=N_Description
 From @YourTable
 Order By N_Code
 For XML Path('tr')
)

Select @N_Data
```

**Returns**

```
<tr>
  <td>123</td>
  <td>Title For 123</td>
  <td>Description for 123 and more text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>ABC</td>
  <td>Title For ABC</td>
  <td>Description for ABC and some additional text</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It is a nice and cleaner approach, but it has the same size limitation. Thanks though!

Comment: @AhmedAli I made no claim this would fix your issue.   The string manipulation seemed odd to me.   I suspect AaronBertrand was correct.